# What varieties of plum tree produce small green plums?

Tags: fruit-trees, identification, plums

My mom thinks it's a [Mirabelle plum tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirabelle_plum) (*Prunus domestica*), but those appear to produce orange plums. It's in southeastern Idaho, gets full sun from about 9 AM until sunset.

What do you think?

<sub>(Click to enlarge pics)</sub>

    [image]


    [image]

Comment: Is the color of the ripened fruit green or are you referring to fruits in its early stages? Most fruits start out green and turn a different color only when they ripen

Comment: @KirkHings Are the mature fruit round or oval in shape? When you wash the wax coating off of a mature fruit, what colour is the skin? Approximately how tall is the tree? Can you describe the taste of a mature fruit? Can you please post a photo of a mature fruit cut open so we can see the colour of the flesh inside...

Comment: These pics taken just two days ago, so I'll have to wait for them to ripen (if they do anymore this year-most things are done for the year in SE Idaho). The tree is about 20ish years old, about 16-20 feet tall. I haven't eaten one, my mom said it isn't the greatest plum but not terrible either. I'll check on these questions though.

Comment: Doh! She always called them green plums for years, and now admits they turn orange at the end. Unless someone can prove otherwise, I'll give a thumbs up to an answer of mirabella.

Comment: @KirkHings You've got to love mothers ;-) I vote for yourself posting the answer & accepting (marking) it as correct - after all you took the time to come back here & update us...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immature Mirabella is the probable answer. I'm posting it here to clear this question from the unanswered list.

Other possibilities based on the picture would be [Damson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damson) plums or immature Satsuma plums ([image](http://scratch.typepad.com/scratch/2009/08/satsuma-plum-crostata.html)).